# Aggregating with length function in dplyr and data.table packages

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, aggregate

I have data.frame which I want to group my columns in dplyr and data.table packages.

So this is my data.frame:

```
df <- data.frame(OwnerUserId = sample(c(-1, 2:10), size = 10),
                  TypeOfId = sample(c(1,2), size = 10, replace = T))

df

## OwnerUserId TypeOfId
## 1           10        1
## 2            6        2
## 3            7        2
## 4            3        2
## 5            2        2
## 6            9        2
## 7           -1        2
## 8            5        1
## 9            8        2
## 10           4        1
```

I want to group with the use of **length** function and have a result like this:

```
new <- aggregate(x = df[, "OwnerUserId"],
                 by = df["OwnerUserId"], 
                 FUN = length)

##    OwnerUserId x
## 1           -1 1
## 2            2 1
## 3            3 1
## 4            4 1
## 5            5 1
## 6            6 1
## 7            7 1
## 8            8 1
## 9            9 1
## 10          10 1
```

I did

```
new <- df %>% group_by(OwnerUserId) %>% summarise(AnswersNumber = length(df[, "OwnerUserId"]))
```

And I got

```
##    OwnerUserId AnswersNumber
##          <dbl>         <int>
##  1          -1            10
##  2           2            10
##  3           3            10
##  4           4            10
##  5           5            10
##  6           6            10
##  7           7            10
##  8           8            10
##  9           9            10
## 10          10            10
```

And it isn't the same result.

Also I tried to do it in data.table, but I get an errors.

Maybe there are some other functions that are analogous to **length** function in **aggregate()**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `n()` in `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
new <- df %>%
    group_by(OwnerUserId) %>% 
    summarise(AnswersNumber = n())
```

and `.N` in `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(AnswersNumber = .N), OwnerUserId]
```

---

The `df[, "OwnerUserId"]` returns the entire column breaking the grouping created with 'OwnerUserId', thus we get the `length` of the whole column instead of the length of the group.  We could instead use `summarise(AnswerNumber = length(OwnerUserId))` as well.  But, `n()` is specialized for this

Comment: Hi and thanks for your solution! It really help me